# HTTP Status 503 on Sun Java System Application Server 9.1_02 (build b04-fcs)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2, glassfish

We are replicating our Production application to our DR machine.  Our application is a web app using Hibernate Spring and Struts2 framework running on a Sun Java System Application Server 9.1_02 (build b04-fcs).  The application is stable on the production environment.  Also made it to run during our first replications.  Recently we encountered an HTTP Status 503.
We tried everything from redeployment to application server (servlet container) restart. We even tried rebuilding the application from source code and redeploying it just to resolve the http status 503.  What could be causing this HTTP status 503? 
Thanks in advance guys.

here are my dependencies/jar files

- antlr-2.7.6.jar
- arpeggio-1.1.jar
- cglib-2.2.jar
- commons-collections-3.1.jar
- commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
- commons-io-2.0.1.jar
- commons-lang-2.4.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- commons-pool-1.4.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- freemarker-2.3.16.jar
- ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
- hibernate3.jar
- javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
- jettison-1.3.2.jar
- jta-1.1.jar
- ldap.jar
- log4j-1.2.14.jar
- mime-util-2.1.3.jar
- ognl-3.0.1.jar
- oracle10g.jar
- org.springframework.asm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.expression-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.orm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.transaction-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
- struts2-core-2.2.3.1.jar
- struts2-json-plugin-2.2.3.1.jar
- struts2-spring-plugin-2.2.3.1.jar
- xwork-core-2.2.3.1.jar

Here is the application server logs

```
Log Entry Detail
```

Timestamp
Apr 25, 2013 17:03:12.981
Log Level
SEVERE
Logger
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
Name-Value Pairs
_ThreadID=14;_ThreadName=pool-1-thread-7;_RequestID=d73c920a-2b6a-4f42-b523-93503d089b74;
Record Number
302
Message ID
PWC1306
Complete Message
Startup of context /myproject failed due to previous errors

```
Log Entry Detail
```

> Timestamp
>   Apr 25, 2013 17:03:12.980
>   Log Level
>   SEVERE
>   Logger
>   javax.enterprise.system.container.web
>   Name-Value Pairs
>   _ThreadID=14;_ThreadName=pool-1-thread-7;_RequestID=d73c920a-2b6a-4f42-b523-93503d089b74;
>   Record Number
>   301
>   Message ID
>   WebModule[/myproject]PWC1275
>   Complete Message
>   Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myprojectSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [hibernate-config/myproject-hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425) at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282) at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204) at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4523) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5184) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:326) at com.sun.enterprise.web.LifecycleStarter.doRun(LifecycleStarter.java:58) at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.runSync(RunnableBase.java:304) at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.run(RunnableBase.java:341) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:432) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:284) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:678) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:703) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1912) at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:796) at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:707) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:4035) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3989) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1398) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375) at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717) at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417) ... 24 more

Comment: maybe a conflict between hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar and 
hibernate3.jar. Try to remove one(first)

Comment: Rebuild with Maven to resolve dependency issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the big clue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
           javax/persistence/OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z
```

It is saying that some code needs to call a method with signature `boolean orphanRemoval()` on the `javax.persistence.OneToMany` API ... but the version of the API that has just been loaded does not provide that methods.

In other words, you have a version mismatch between some of the JARs in the WAR file.

I don't think this is a mismatch between the hibernate and hibernate-jpa files because the JBoss Hibernate 3.x release zips have files with those names.

Instead, I think it is a mismatch between Hibernate and Spring.  In particular, the [Spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate) says:

> Note: As of Spring 3.0, Spring requires Hibernate 3.2 or later.

It is not clear what version of Hibernate 3 you are using, but my theory is that it is too old for Spring 3.0.x.

Comment: a version mismatch is my first guess but what could cause a version mismatch all of a sudden on the DR server when the exact same copy of the application is working on the production server. 
Still i will try your suggested answer and update you guys with the result.

Comment: @Stepeh C better late than never.  Got mixed up with other projects forgot to update this answer.  It was indeed a conflict between and some missing jar dependencies.